# Getting Mouse Position in C# Over a PictureBox

Tags: c#, forms

the question as  briefly stated in the title already sounds bad. Anyways, Ive been trying to grab mouse coordinates over a C# form application and its very simple to do that using OnMouseMove built in function. The problem is when there is a picturebox in the form application, the function cant get the coordinates, because the picturebox window is not being selected! What do I mean is the cursor isnt pointing to the parts which is being blocked by the picture box window!

I tried also to use

```
private void drawbox_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    x2 = e.X;
    y2 = e.Y;
    label6.Location = new Point(x2, y2);
    base.OnMouseMove(e);
}
```

but no luck.

I looked up for the issue but I couldnt find a fix. Please help.

For your information, Im using the following function to get mouse coordinates:

```
protected override void OnMouseMove( MouseEventArgs e)
{
    x2 =e.X;
    y2 = e.Y;
    label6.Location = new Point(x2, y2);
    base.OnMouseMove(e);
    //base.OnMouseMove(e);
}
```

Comment: you want the mouse point inside the picturebox(relative to the picturebox) , or when the mouse passes over the picturebox grab the point relative to the form?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the quick reply, drawbox is an instance of picturebox, and to be frank, Im going to need position for both cases, with respect to picture box and with respect to form. What I want to do later on is to draw some objects and then save the image.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use an API call for this - I implemented the following code in a reusable class a while back, and it's worked nicely.

```
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    private static extern bool GetCursorPos(ref System.Drawing.Point lpPoint);

    public static System.Drawing.Point GetCursorPosition()
    {
        System.Drawing.Point p = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
        GetCursorPos(ref p);
        return p;
    }
```

Call it like this:

```
    Point p = GetCursorPos();
```

This should give position relative to the form. If you want the picturebox position, add the top and left coordinates of the box to the X and Y coordinates of p (respectively).

EDIT: Invocation was wrong.

EDIT 2: For the problem of not being able to capture the mouse position over the PictureBox, just forward the PictureBox's MouseMove event to the form.

Select the PictureBox in designer, then open Events (the lightning bolt). Click once on the empty box beside MouseMove, then either:

1. Double-click to create a handler method, and call your OnMouseMove method from there

   OR
2. Change your OnMouseMove method  to have this signature:

   ```
    private void OnMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
   ```

Comment: I dont mean to criticize, but what I dont understand is  GetCursorPosition() is not being called. 

Thanks!

Comment: You'll have to call it in your OnMouseMove, then use the.x and .y like you do with the MouseEventArgs.

Comment: This is my entire form code, Ive made it to do some testings.

Comment: Remove thebase.OnMouseMove(e); in your code, and change your x1 = Convert and y1 = Convert lines to 
   int.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out x1);
   int.TryParse(textBox2.Text, out y1);

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help you. I place the information on this.Text just for demonstration:

```
        private void drawbox_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {

            Point p = e.Location;
            Point formpoint = PointToClient(MousePosition);

            this.Text = formpoint.ToString() + " - " + p.ToString();
        }

        private void Form1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            this.Text = e.Location.ToString();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

@christophos
Here is my entire code, its no that long. Ive written it for testing and sadly stills "label6" doesnt move over my picturebox "drawbox". This is what I initially had done, it works perfectly if there is no picturebox.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Graphics drawingarea;
    int x1, y1,x2,y2 = 0;

    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern bool GetCursorPos(ref Point lpPoint);


    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        drawingarea = drawbox.CreateGraphics();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Pen blackpen = new Pen(Color.Black);
        x1 = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
        y1 = Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text);
        //x2 = Convert.ToInt32(textBox3.Text);
        //y2 = Convert.ToInt32(textBox4.Text);
        drawingarea.DrawLine(blackpen, x1, y1, x2, y2);
    }

    protected override void OnMouseMove( MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        Point p = GetCursorPosition();
        x2 = p.X;
        y2 = p.Y;
        label6.Location = new Point(x2, y2);
        base.OnMouseMove(e);
    }
    public static Point GetCursorPosition()
    {
        Point p = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
        GetCursorPos(ref p);
        return p;
        }
}
```